# multiple currencies in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

How to make a MySQL table that could contain multiple type of currencies ($, Euros, ...) ? And if I want to make a final report is their a way to make a sum of those currencies other than adding multiple if statements to the sum ?

Comment: I'd use two columns, one with the value in a `decimal`, one with currency in `varchar`

Comment: Or `currencyid` (foreign key  to `currencies` table.)

Comment: As for the calculation, you could join to a table that holds the exchange rate...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you talking about a kind of order table or the like where *different* orders can have different currencies? Or more like an item table where the *same* item has prices in different currencies?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sometimes in a store people pays with different currencies. This make the final financial report is bit hard to make (at least for me). How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There may be several aspects involved. So here is some brainstorming:

- You offer the same product in different currencies, e.g. a toy for 10 EUR or 11 USD. So you'd probably have an item table plus an item_price table, where the latter has product number, currency and price. (An alternative would be to have just one price, e.g. in USD and a currency table with conversion rates and you'd calculate the foreign price. But then you'd get "ugly" prices, e.g. 10.57, rather than typical prices like 10.50, 10.90 or 10.99. But well, you could have a price adjustment funtion for that, too. And you'd have to keep your conversion tables up-to-date or live with possible losses.)
- A customer buys products and pays the bill. The bill is in one currency (store price and currency in the bill), but you also get your money in your currency, as PayPal or the bank convert it at a daily rate. Do you need to store this real amount, too? Then that would be another column in your bill.
- I don't know how it is about taxes. Different currencies sounds like different countries. Maybe you'd have to deal with these in your database, too. I just don't know. The prices you show and store are usually gross prices (the price a customer actually pays) and the taxes (could be different VAT percentages with different products in one single bill) would have to be calculated.
- As to getting sums: with all the information stored you'd get them with joins from the tables. No if-then-else in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

- As per my opinion you can create a Country Table which contains
  CountryID, CountryName, CurrencyCode, ExchangeRate. Now In that
  country table you have to add all countries which you want to add but
  you have to keep one thing in mind that you have to decide 1 currency
  as base currency and put exchangeRate as 1 for that currency and
  convert all other currencies exchangeRate  based on the base currency
  and insert into that table. i.e. Keep base currency as USD so insert
  1 record with USD and exchangeRate must be 1 for that currency.
  Suppose I am adding India as country than exchangeRate for that
  country is based on USD as 66.40 Rs. insert all other countries
  according to this entries.
- Now when you want to add any transaction related to money in any
  table then keep exchangeRate column with that amount column. ind
  insert the exchangeRate and amount same as user's currency. i.e. If
  my user is in India country, so it's currency is INR. Now that user
  wants to add 1000 Rs. then you have to enter that 1000 Rs amount in
  transaction table as it is without any conversion with exchange Rate
  of 66.40 (fetch from country table). Same way If user currency is USD
  and he wants to add a transaction of 100$ than store 100 as Amount
  and exchangeRate as 1.
- Now when you want to create any reports then just divide exchangeRate
  with Amount, so you will get report in your base currency and after
  conversion in base currency you can generate each report in any
  currency as per your requirement.